How the Shobogenzo is laid out?
I am looking at the Shobogenzo, where, in addition to writing the text on the computer, they have an image showing vertical (seemingly right-to-left) text:



What are the main details/takeaways from the structure of the Shobogenzo here?

Is it vertical and right to left?
What does the whitespace and the vertical lines signify?
Why are some columns only 1 or 2 or a few characters, and others long? Does length have any significance?
Is it all just part of a poem or prose, or are there titles and subtitles and section headings throughout the Shobogenzo in that link somewhere?
How about, why is it divided into 1 page in 3 sections? Is that a standard of the past or anything?

I don't read Chinese yet, but looking to capture this text into structured data and need to know the meaning of how it's structured.

Are you aware that vertical writing is common and  was once standard in Japanese and also Chinese?

@Yosh "Once standard in Japanese"?  I'd say it's still fairly standard in printed material:  novels, manga, and newspapers.  Online, things are definitely a bit different.

@A.Ellett You are right. I chose the wrong wording to mean that horizontal writing was much less prevalent back then. Partly I was distracted by technical books I'm buried with right now.

If you're totally new to vertical writing in general, please read this as a starter.

Is it vertical and right to left?

Yes.

What does the whitespace and the vertical lines signify?

Apparently, what is shown on this page is not the actual main text of Shobogenzo, but rather forewords written by someone other than Dogen, explanations of how this version of Shobogenzo was created, and descriptions of the book's structure. The two long vertical lines are simply separators dividing these sections, which likely do not exist in the original handwritten version of the book. The short texts on the right side of these separators are dates and the names of the authors of the forewords. You often see such elements indented in English texts and letters as well, don't you?

Why are some columns only 1 or 2 or a few characters, and others long? Does length have any significance?

The two two-character lines in the bottom column are simply subheadings.

Is it all just part of a poem or prose, or are there titles and subtitles and section headings throughout the Shobogenzo in that link somewhere?

The three large texts read:

正法眼蔵 = Shobogenzo
彫刻永平正法眼蔵縁由 = Chokoku Eihei Shobo Genzo: Origin
彫刻永平正法眼蔵凡例 = Chokoku Eihei Shobo Genzo: Legends
("Legends" as in explanatory notes, not legendary stories)

So they're obviously titles and headings. According to this leaflet (PDF), 彫刻永平正法眼蔵 is one of the printed versions of Shobogenzo made circa 1800.

How about, why is it divided into 1 page in 3 sections? Is that a standard of the past or anything?

It's simply a vertical version of column layout, which is particularly common in modern magazines and newspapers. I believe such layout was not used when Shobogenzo was first written by Dogen in the 13th century.
